# Issue Using SDWebImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm trying to use SDWebImage in swift, the file id like to use is called UIImageView+WebCache.h

i added it to my bridging header using

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

Now i am trying to load that file in swift using:

```
var webCah = UIImageView+WebCache()
```

and i get an error message reading:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'WebCache'

I believe it thinks i am trying to use a uiimageview, when i am just trying to use that objective-c class

How Do i Call that class properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImageView+WebCache` is category that extends the functionality `UIImageView` with SDWebImage specific methods. You need to access the methods defined in it on a `UIImageView` object.

Example code:

```
var imageView :UIImageView = UIImageView() // example, this will probably come from elsewhere in your app
imageView.sd_imageURL
// Or

imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad
```

Look at the documentation to see what methods are available, or the source https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView%2BWebCache.h

Comment: I just stared using swift a few days ago, How would i do that?

Comment: See my edit. Once you have a UIImageView object, you can access those methods using the dot notation in Swift

Comment: how would i use something like this func sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder;

Comment: The same way you call any other method in Swift on an object `objectName.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholder:image)` or similar, not sure on the syntax, not at my dev machine at the moment.

Comment: @Jeff HI Jeff!
I am also facing the same issue. Can you please let me know what all steps you followed to get this worked?

Comment: Not sure what else to describe other than what is already in the answer